# React Tippy - Using method setIsOpen()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tippyjs

I'm using React Tippy - a React component based on Tippy.js. I want to use the [documented setIsOpen method](https://github.com/tvkhoa/react-tippy#showhide-your-tooltip-manually) - but it's not working.

```
TypeError: setIsOpen is not a function.
```

Can't seem to find any documentation or issues related to this. Any ideas?

My code is:

```
<Tooltip
  position="right"
  animation="scale"
  arrow="true"
  arrowSize="big"
  theme="light"
  trigger="click focus"
  interactive
  open={open}
  html={(
    <div className="tooltip-body">
      <span className="info icon-sm-info"></span>
      <span className="close" onClick={() => { setIsOpen(false) }}>&#215;</span>
      <h5>Hello</h5>
      <div>Tooltip Content</div>
    </div>
  )}
>
<span className="icon-sm-info">Hello</span>
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: you need to provide implementation for setIsOpen manually. do you have any implementation then plz post and you tried this {this.setIsOpen(false)}.

Comment: Yep, I've tried that. It gets the `this` context with the arrow function anyway. `setIsOpen` should be supported, it's in the source file here... but I'm not how it's working: https://github.com/tvkhoa/react-tippy/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: Your answer before you deleted helped me figure it out. Need to use state.

Comment: if it was helpful mark as accepted :D

Comment: react recompose they are using thats why example is work. in your case scenario is different. hope so it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your state :

```
this.state = {open : false}

setIsOpen = () => {
this.setState(state => { open : true});
}
```

Updated Code

```
<Tooltip
  position="right"
  animation="scale"
  arrow="true"
  arrowSize="big"
  theme="light"
  trigger="click focus"
  interactive
  open={open}
  html={(
    <div className="tooltip-body">
      <span className="info icon-sm-info"></span>
      <span className="close" onClick={() => { this.setIsOpen() }}>&#215;</span>
      <h5>Hello</h5>
      <div>Tooltip Content</div>
    </div>
  )}
>
<span className="icon-sm-info">Hello</span>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it by using state.

```
class ToolTip extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         open: false
      }
   }

   setIsOpen = (option) => {
      this.setState({
         open: option
      });
   }

<span className="close" onClick={() => {this.setIsOpen(false)}}>&#215;</span>
```